# Making a coordinates list using another list(TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list that contains coordinates using another list like so:

```
test = ['62r', '29a', '8v', '52b', '59c', '37n', '35n', '48r', '12n', '49m', '4a', '23a', '21r', '31r', '45r', '36a', '58g', '6e', '15b']

redHeights = []
for value in test:
    if 'r' in value:
       redHeights.append(value[:-1])

def coordinates(height):
    width = 8
    coord = x, y = (height%width), (int(height/width))
    return coord

newRedChannel = [coordinates(height) for height in redHeights]
print(newRedChannel, '\n')
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Randomizing Function\Decrypter1.py", line 13, in <module>
    newRedChannel = [coordinates(height) for height in redHeights]
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Randomizing Function\Decrypter1.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    newRedChannel = [coordinates(height) for height in redHeights]
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Randomizing Function\Decrypter1.py", line 10, in coordinates
    coord = x, y = (height%width), (int(height/width))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Before taking the remainder of the division you need to convert the `height` (which is `str`) to `int`. For example in the `newRedChannel` list comprehension:

```
test = ['62r', '29a', '8v', '52b', '59c', '37n', '35n', '48r', '12n', '49m', '4a', '23a', '21r',
        '31r', '45r', '36a', '58g', '6e', '15b']

redHeights = []
for value in test:
    if 'r' in value:
        redHeights.append(value[:-1])


def coordinates(height):
    width = 8
    coord = (height % width), (height / width)
    return coord


newRedChannel = [coordinates(int(height)) for height in redHeights]
print(newRedChannel, '\n')
```

Output:

```
[(6, 7.75), (0, 6.0), (5, 2.625), (7, 3.875), (5, 5.625)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the fact that `height` is of type `str`, therefore you must convert to `int` prior to performing any numeric operations with it. You can also highly simplify your code, like so:

```
redHeights = [value[:-1] for value in test if 'r' in value]

newRedChannel = [((int(height) % 8), (int(height) / 8)) for height in redHeights]
```

Which yields:

```
[(6, 7.75), (0, 6.0), (5, 2.625), (7, 3.875), (5, 5.625)]
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is add this:

```
redHeights = list(map(int, redHeights))
```

I didn't realize that I DID do that but I wrote that line inside of a `print` method which I completely missed and that threw me off entirely * extreme amounts of faceplams *:

```
print(list(map(int, redHeights)))
```